# printing sheet to fill the square sheet with the stamps without any overlapping

Tags: c

I have written the following C program for an online course. It seems to be working and giving relevant output, but when I submit the program, I am told it gives a "wrong answer".

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() { 

    long int n; 

    scanf(“%ld”,&n); 

    if(n>1) { 
        if(n%2||n%3)
            printf(“YES”); 
        else 
            printf(“NO”);
    } 
    else if(n==1) { 
        printf(“NO”); 
    } 

    return 0; 
}
```

This is what the program is supposed to do:

> Ted (the popular talking bear) has been given a job at the printing firm. Looking at his previous employment record, the firm is watching very strictly on his work product. Recently, he has been assigned a task to print on a square sheet of dimension NxN. You may think of the sheet containing N2 cells of dimension 1x1 each. Since, Ted is a lazy bear, he somehow steals two stamps, a horizontal printing stamp which covers a 1*2 block and a vertical printing stamp which covers a 3*1 block. He may use these two stamps in any order and as many times as he wants. But the sheets are old, if the sheet is stamped twice at any cell, it will tear off. Now, there is a shipment of sheets coming with varying sizes. But he observes that in some of the cases it is not possible to completely fill the square sheet with no overlapping stamps. So, he asks for your help in deciding whether it is possible to fill the square sheet with the stamps without any overlapping.
>
> Input consists of a single integer N denoting the side of the square sheet.
>
> Output a single line containing “YES” (without quotes) if it is possible to fill the square sheet without overlapping the stamps and “NO” (without quotes) otherwise.
>
> Constraints:
>
> > 1 ≤ N ≤ 106
>
> Sample Input:
>
> ```
> 2
> ```
>
> Sample Output:
>
> ```
> YES
> ```

How can I fix my program?

Comment: I have written the program and its even working and giving relevant output but when i submit the program it is showing"wrong answer".it  is for online course.here is my program in c .#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
long int n;
scanf(“%ld”,&n);
if(n>1)
{
if(n%2||n%3)
{
printf(“YES”);
}
else
{
printf(“NO”);
}
}
else if(n==1)
{
printf(“NO”);
}
return 0;
}

Comment: Post your code along with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if your algorithm is correct, but I think that instead of:

```
if(n%2||n%3)
```

you wanted to write:

```
if(n%2 == 0 || n%3 == 0)
```

Here `n%2 == 0` means that `n` is divisible by 2.

Comment: I'm glad to have been of help :)